# Sagemaker Studio Lab GPU not working with pytorch

Tags: pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I can't get the GPU to work even though i chose the GPU option with 4 hours at the start. Is there something to do in order to activate it?

[image]

edit:

I installed pytorch with cuda:
%conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.4 -c pytorch

Answer (score 0):

Could you try building a custom environment via the YAML file option, using something like this (below is just an example file that works for me, you can add remove packages specific to your use case)

```
name: torch
channels:
    - pytorch
dependencies:
  - python=3.9
  - pip
  - pip:
    - ipywidgets
  - conda
  - conda:
    - ipykernel
    - pytorch
    - torchvision
    - torchaudio
    - torchserve
    - cudatoolkit=11.3
    - sklearn
```